# Error while inserting into: no viable alternative at input 'with'

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr

I'm getting the error

> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: No viable alternative at input 'with' to insert in a table.

while executing the following insert query:

```
INSERT INTO users partition(date)
WITH existentes AS (SELECT COUNT(1) AS name FROM users WHERE date=20160303)
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the order:

```
WITH existentes AS (SELECT COUNT(1) AS name FROM users WHERE date=20160303)
INSERT INTO users partition(date)
```